What is the alternative to setting $base_url?
I have spun up fresh instance of Drupal commerce via Composer. The installation is at https://drupal.modhaka.com/web/.
However, few modules like Social Auth are expecting the front page to be https://drupal.modhaka.com/.
From Drupal 7's experience I understand that settings.php's $base_url is where the base URL has to be set, but this has now been removed from Drupal 8 onwards. The alternative is not very clear in the hyperlinked article either.
I would like to learn how to address this.
I have tried to set the domain (https://drupal.modhaka.com) to the path which contains the /web folder. However, Drupal is trying to reach the server in the /web directory again whenever there is an action/event, thereby returning a 404 page error. So, somewhere the Drupal server settings pertain with respect to base URL which am unable to figure out.

This is no Drupal issue. It's a server issue. You need to point your domain to /path/to/drupal/web on your server and not to /path/to/drupal/

@leymannx - Sorry I should have mentioned earlier that I have already done that. But what Drupal is trying is on click of links it is trying to reach to "/web" again thereby returning 404 page error! So, somewhere the Drupal server settings pertain with respect to base URL.


I have tried to set the domain (https://drupal.modhaka.com) to the path which contains the /web folder.

Yes, this is the correct way. Pointing the domain to the up-level directory is unsafe because this exposes the /vendor folder which shouldn't be accessible.

However, Drupal is trying to reach the server in the /web directory again whenever there is an action/event, thereby returning a 404 page error. So, somewhere the Drupal server settings pertain with respect to base URL which am unable to figure out.

There is no Drupal setting for the base URL, Drupal figures this out automatically. However, if you did run the Drupal site with a different base path the render cache is full of incorrect URLs. You have to clear the cache after changing the web server configuration.

I have cleared the browser cache multiple times, still the redirection happens to /web appended in the domain URL. I am still wondering why this is happening. Drupal internally is redirecting the links to contain '/web' somehow.

If web is the server document root directory, it should not appear in the URL. What described in this answer is what probably happens, if we exclude a wrongly configured server.
